# ffmpeg converting JPG slideshow to H264

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, mkv

I am trying to convert a set of jpg files to a slideshow with varying durations using ffconcat

output.txt contents:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file slide_0001.jpg
duration 0.163
file slide_0002.jpg
duration 0.533
file slide_0003.jpg
duration 1.067
file slide_0004.jpg
duration 0.533
file slide_0005.jpg
etc.
```

FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i output.txt output.mkv
```

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i output.txt -c:v copy output.mkv
```

However, when converting, the colours of the images become skewed.
White becomes pink / purple and dark green becomes light green.
The same happens when choosing different codecs and containers.
Is there a way to solve this?

EDIT:
I performed the same conversion again. I attached the log output as requested.
However, in the meantime I have figured out that converting without ffconcat duration and then altering timecodes with mp4fpsmod is more efficient in terms of storage (3 vs 40 MB) and gives less issues in different players. The result is nonetheless the same: colours are still wrong, both on my workstation (Ubuntu 18.04) and laptop (macOS Mojave).

I tried to alter things with `pix_fmt` and `-vf format` as can be seen in the second log output. This did not solve the problem.

Background info:
The input jpg files are from a lecture recording made with MediaSite, which has both a video stream for the room as well as this slideshow stream for the slides.

Example of input:
[image: Input image]
Example of output:
[image: Screenshot of output]
log output MKV conversion:

```
    $ ffmpeg -i outputnew.txt output12345.mkv
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from 'outputnew.txt':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'output12345.mkv':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj444p(pc), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[mjpeg @ 0x7fb284061200] EOI missing, emulating=00:02:12.96 bitrate= 491.3kbits/s speed=14.3x        
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 487.2kbits/s speed=14.3x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 333.0kbits/s speed=22.3x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 338.8kbits/s speed=22.7x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 164.7kbits/s speed=41.6x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 122.7kbits/s speed=55.7x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 111.2kbits/s speed=60.5x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte= 105.3kbits/s speed=64.4x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  82.2kbits/s speed=82.7x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  79.7kbits/s speed=85.8x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  59.7kbits/s speed= 114x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  53.8kbits/s speed= 127x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  54.7kbits/s speed= 124x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  47.1kbits/s speed= 143x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  47.0kbits/s speed= 144x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  44.6kbits/s speed= 151x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  34.4kbits/s speed= 194x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  32.9kbits/s speed= 204x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  32.8kbits/s speed= 203x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  32.6kbits/s speed= 202x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  28.8kbits/s speed= 229x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  27.9kbits/s speed= 236x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  27.9kbits/s speed= 233x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  23.9kbits/s speed= 274x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  24.2kbits/s speed= 273x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  24.2kbits/s speed= 274x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  24.0kbits/s speed= 276x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  24.2kbits/s speed= 273x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  23.6kbits/s speed= 278x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  23.7kbits/s speed= 279x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  23.6kbits/s speed= 279x    
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  24.0kbits/s speed= 276x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  23.5kbits/s speed= 281x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  20.4kbits/s speed= 325x    
[mjpeg @ 0x7fb28502a000] EOI missing, emulating
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  20.1kbits/s speed= 329x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x7fb284812e00] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=  20.1kbits/s speed= 330x    
frame=  635 fps= 14 q=-1.0 Lsize=   37389kB time=04:22:06.76 bitrate=  19.5kbits/s speed= 343x    
video:37378kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.029620%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] frame I:16    Avg QP:11.98  size:154224
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] frame P:184   Avg QP:13.30  size: 79029
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] frame B:435   Avg QP:13.19  size: 48887
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] consecutive B-frames:  6.0%  4.4% 10.9% 78.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] mb I  I16..4: 55.7%  0.0% 44.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] mb P  I16..4: 32.4%  0.0% 21.5%  P16..4: 13.3% 15.1% 11.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 6.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] mb B  I16..4: 17.8%  0.0%  7.2%  B16..8: 19.1% 19.4%  6.5%  direct:14.6%  skip:15.3%  L0:47.0% L1:38.9% BI:14.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] coded y,u,v intra: 63.7% 26.1% 56.3% inter: 46.5% 24.6% 43.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 18% 58%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 20% 25%  4%  4%  3%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.4% UV:5.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] ref P L0: 43.2%  4.4% 30.8% 21.4%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] ref B L0: 64.1% 27.3%  8.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] ref B L1: 85.3% 14.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb284802800] kb/s:19.25
```

Log output mp4 conversion:

```
$ ffmpeg -i slide_%04d.jpg -vf format=rgba -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -movflags +faststart -preset veryslow output12345.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'slide_%04d.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:25.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output12345.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7fb7e280b000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output12345.mp4':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[mp4 @ 0x7fb7e1801800] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file     
frame=  634 fps=8.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2252kB time=00:00:25.24 bitrate= 731.0kbits/s speed=0.337x    
video:2245kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.307448%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] frame I:5     Avg QP:19.12  size: 49393
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] frame P:131   Avg QP:22.18  size:  9379
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] frame B:498   Avg QP:23.78  size:  1652
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] consecutive B-frames:  3.2%  1.6%  3.3% 29.7%  7.9% 16.1%  7.7% 16.4% 14.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] mb I  I16..4: 45.7% 37.9% 16.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] mb P  I16..4:  6.0%  5.3%  1.3%  P16..4: 19.9%  1.9%  3.7%  0.3%  0.1%    skip:61.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.4%  0.1%  B16..8: 17.5%  1.0%  0.2%  direct: 0.3%  skip:80.2%  L0:52.3% L1:46.9% BI: 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] 8x8 transform intra:43.0% inter:48.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] direct mvs  spatial:99.2% temporal:0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 16.9% 25.8% 16.6% inter: 1.1% 1.9% 1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 61% 28%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20%  9% 50%  3%  4%  3%  3%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 23% 19%  5%  7%  6%  6%  5% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 40% 13%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.3% UV:5.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] ref P L0: 33.2%  3.1% 11.6%  7.3%  8.8%  6.4%  6.5%  3.1%  3.2%  2.6%  2.4%  2.5%  2.8%  2.8%  2.3%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] ref B L0: 42.0% 15.1% 12.0%  5.4%  4.9%  4.3%  4.0%  1.9%  2.0%  1.8%  1.7%  1.8%  1.7%  1.1%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] ref B L1: 83.5% 16.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb7e1803c00] kb/s:725.10
```

Player:
QuickTime, VLC and Kodi on both Linux and Mac.

EDIT 2:
Input files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kbBkSDSwe6ywgQ8lkjqkh-MKCzGA4bj8

Comment: Looks like a bug. I made a [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7625). A crappy workaround is to convert jpg to png with `convert` or whatever and then use `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Looks to me like your JPGs might be CMYK and would need to be converted to RGB to preserve your colors. Conversion can be done in ImageMagick using -colorspace or using profiles. The latter is the better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending almost half a day on this, I have managed to find a (not so pretty) solution to my problem:

### Step 1

`cd` to folder with slides.
Convert images from .jpg to .png using ImageMagick to prevent colour problems

```
mogrify -format png *.jpg
```

### Step 2

Convert and put .png images into mp4 file using FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i slide_%04d.png -c:v libx264 -vf mergeplanes=0x010200:format=gbrp -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow output.mp4
```

### Step 3

Using [mp4fpsmod](https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod), alter the timecode of the newly created file

```
mp4fpsmod -t timecode.txt output.mp4 -o timedoutput.mp4
```

Example of timecode.txt

```
# timecode format v2
163
696
1763
2296
2829
3363
```

The resulting file has a size of around 5 MB, whereas the original .jpg files have a size of 122 MB, which is great.

### Remaining problems

The file plays well in QuickTime, but unfortunately not in VLC. 
I will create a new question for this, because I need VLC to play this file together with an mp4 video and be able to scroll through the videos simultaneously.

However, if you read this and know the answer, please do not hesitate to comment here.

EDIT: Incorporated changes as suggested by user llogan solving the colour issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to delete the first line and add quote marks in your text file:

```
file 'slide_0001.jpg'
duration 0.163
file 'slide_0002.jpg'
duration 0.533
file 'slide_0003.jpg'
duration 1.067
file 'slide_0004.jpg'
duration 0.533
file 'slide_0005.jpg'
etc.
```

The command should be:
    ffmpeg -f concat -i png.txt -vf fps=25 output.mp4

I've tested this and it works.

Comment: According to this source: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1, I should include the first line.
The conversion does work and the timing is correct, however the colours are off.

Comment: I'm using Win7 so that worked for me and I had no problem with the colors. I tried using the first line, as the help files state but sometimes it worked, sometimes it froze up.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not with mine. I added some of the input files to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This was bug [#7625](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7625). It was fixed on 2018-12-18:

[lavc/mjpegdec: Interpret three-component Adobe transform 0 also as RGB](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=06a436a224c00b97c0d2a173be2f5d792fd643db)

[Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) a recent build from the git master branch and the fix will be included. For old versions a workaround proposed by Gyan in the bug report comments is to use a filter: `mergeplanes=0x010200:format=gbrp`.